# when do globals go in .bss and .data?

Tags: c

In C, global variables are initialized to default value by the standard, if left uninitialized. When will the .bss section be used then (I had thought this was for uninitialized globals)?

For example,

```
int i = 7;
int j;

int main(){
...
}
```

I would've before expected `j` to go in `.bss` and `i` to go in `.data`. I'm specifically concerned about how this would work if I want to use `j` in another module, but it is initially uninitialized in this module, where it is later defined. Would I just use `extern int j;` in the other module?

Comment: Does j not go in .bss?

Comment: Yes: in the other module - compilation unit - you should use extern int j;

Answer (score 2):

Many implementations use the .data section for objects which are defined with an initializer, and the .bss section for those that aren't.  Depending upon the target platform, the code image may contain a copy of the initial contents of the .data section and an instruction for the loader to zero out the contents of .bss, or the code image may contain a constant read-only section which is the same size as the .data section, along with startup code that will copy the contents of that section to the .data section and zeroe out the .bss section.

This design isn't universal.  Some implementations may store the initial contents of the .data section in a compressed format and generate code that uncompresses it, and some freestanding implementations may require that all objects of static duration be static const (a restriction which would allow their generated code to be loaded as a "plug-in" in contexts that, for various reasons, require that any data which is to be persisted between function calls be managed through the host application).  A few for Harvard-architecture machines will simply generate a sequence of explicit load-immediate and store-direct instructions to initialize everything.

The design of having .const hold immutable data, .data hold initialized data, and .bss hold zero-filled data, although not universal, is common enough that programmers should expect most implementations to use it absent documentation to the contrary.  It works well, and tools which use it will interact smoothly with each other, even when processing code written in different languages.

Answer (score 2):

> In C, global variables are initialized to default value by the standard, if left uninitialized.

Yes, supposing we take "global" (not a C term) to mean "declared at file scope".  The same applies to other objects with static storage duration too (*i.e.* variables declared at block scope with the keyword `static`).

> When will the .bss section be used then (I had thought this was for uninitialized globals)?

It's entirely up to the C implementation.  Whether there even is such a thing as a .bss section is implementation-specific.  However, in implementations for systems where ".bss section" means something, it is common for objects that

- have static storage duration, AND
- have no initializer or are explicitly initialized with the same value that they would receive in the absence of an initializer

to be stored in the .bss section of compiled binaries.  Such a section does not contain explicit values, so objects that have non-default initial values cannot be stored in such a section without engaging some kind of shim to initialize them from data stored elsewhere, which moots the usual advantages attributed to .bss.

Of course, implementations are free to put fewer objects in .bss if they so choose, based on whatever rules they like.

> For example, [...] I would've before expected `j` to go in `.bss` and `i` to go in `.data`.

That sounds plausible, but so what?

> I'm specifically concerned about how this would work if I want to use `j` in another module, but it is initially uninitialized in this module, where it is later defined. Would I just use `extern int j;` in the other module?

That has nothing in particular to do with `.bss` or `.data` sections.  Again, those are implementation-specific considerations.  The C language spec gives the rules for accessing objects defined in one translation unit (roughly: source file) from another, and to a very good approximation, you don't need to care about the underlying implementation details.

If you want to access an object, such as the one identified by `j`, from multiple different translation units in your program, then this is what you must do:

- exactly one translation unit must declare `j` at file scope, without `static`, and either with an initializer or without (explicit) `extern` or both.  This ensures that that TU provides an external definition of `j`.
- in all other translations where the same `j` is to be accessed, it must be declared explicitly `extern` and without an initializer (for example, `extern int j;`).  This is usually achieved by putting such a declaration in a header and `#include`ing the header.  Within the scope of such a declaration, `j` refers to the "global" `j`.
- all the declarations must specify compatible type.

You having done that, it is the responsibility of your compiler and linker to hook it all together properly.  You do not need to be concerned with details such as which section of the executable contains `j`.

Comment: So based on your answer `int j;` in Module A and `extern int j;` in Module B is okay then?

Comment: Yes, @user18348324, that combination is fine.  But it would be even better for the former to be `int j = 0;`.

Answer (score -1):

You focus on implementation details which are not important here.

If defined in the translation unit scope (using your terminology "global"):

```
int j = 7;
int i;
```

It is guaranteed by the C standard tat `j` will be initialized and hold the value `7` and 'i' will be zeroed before the `main` function starts. How will it be done does not matter to you.

`extern int i,j;` will not change anything as functions in that module cannot be called before the `main` function. The `extern` *only* shows the compiler that `i` and `j` are defined in another compilation unit and only gives information on their **types**

**1** Note: If you use some compiler extensions like gcc `__attribute__((constructor))` the function having this attribute will be called before function main. In this function you need to assume that global variables are not initialized.

Comment: Interesting. why did I attract so many DVs?